# Execute code after scrolling a certain amount of pixels from a certain point (up or down)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently making an overlay that covers a sticky top bar when the user has scrolled beyond a certain point (down) and disappears when scrolling back up. However, I'd like to be able to scroll for at least 50px before the code is executed (something like a gap before the overlay is triggered).

```
$(function() {
var prevScroll = $(document).scrollTop(); //initial position 

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var newScroll = $(document).scrollTop(); //position from top after scrolling 

    if(newScroll > prevScroll) { // checks if the user has scrolled up or down
            var fromNew = $(document).scrollTop(); // holds value to compare with the position + gap amount

            if (fromNew > newScroll + 50) { //checks to see if scrolled for 50px
                $("#stick-start").fadeIn("fast");
                prevScroll = newScroll + 50; //initial position + scrolled amount
            };

    } else {
            var fromNew = $(document).scrollTop();

            if (fromNew > newScroll - 50) {
                if ($("#stick-start").hasClass("is-stuck")) {
                    $("#stick-start").fadeOut("fast");
                    prevScroll = newScroll - 50;
                };
            };
         };
     });
});
```

The condition that checks whether you're scrolling up or down works. But as it is now, the overlay just keeps fading in and out repeatedly. How do I make it so that you have to scroll at least 50px before anything happens ?

Comment: Both your if and your else conditional are creating new scroll handlers, every time they execute.  And for a scroll event, those events happen **a lot**.  Don't create duplicate event bindings.

Comment: The simple answer is to make one scroll event handler, inside **it** check the if/else, and only do what is needed.  Don't create/toggle/juggle multiple scroll event handlers

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you where you're going.

```
var $document = $(document);
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= 50) {
    $("#stick-start").fadeIn("fast");
  } else {
    $("#stick-start").fadeOut("fast");
  }
});
```

EDIT: had an error, should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {
      $("#stick-start").fadeIn();
   } else {
       $("#stick-start").fadeOut();
   }
});
```